# Loading large image in parts in Timage component

Tags: delphi, image-processing, timage

I have a large images on server. When user request for any one I download them on to the client machine and once it is complete I load it into Timage control.

Now what client is requesting that the image must come in chunks(parts) and as soon as a chunk is downloaded it must be shown in Timage control and as soon as other chunk downloaded it must be appended to previously loaded image.

I am not getting how to proceed for the same. I am using Delphi 2006

Comment: What is the format of the images on the server?  Bitmap?  Jpeg?

Comment: its jpeg image that I am trying to load

Comment: How are those images going to be displayed? I guess that unless you have such a huge screen resolution, or very poor download speed, you should be capable to download a full screen image very fast and therefore you shouldn't need to show it in chunks. Do you want to be able to navigate in the image, like google maps does?

Comment: Yes they are basically Geo referenced maps, and yes I have to replicated the Gmaps effect

Answer (score 1):

Create `bm`, an empty (whiter or black) `TBitmap` with the same size as the entire image. Then download each cell of the image one by one. When a new cell is downloaded, draw it (for instance, using `BitBlt` or `Draw`) on the right part of `bm`.